# Where can I ask a question regarding anti-virus software?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have the following question to ask:

> Any component of my computer is not working after the expiration date of anti-virus "Kaspersky".
>
> Now I want to use "Avast" antivirus in my computer.
>
> How can I do that since my computer is not responding at all?

Is there a site within the Stack Exchange network where such a question would be appropriate?

Comment: "Any component of my computer is not working" - it could be diagnosed as power supply problem, since without power any other component would not function. Is this your case? This is how you've described it.

Comment: This isn't a question regarding anti-virus software, to be honest. It's a question regarding a problem with a PC.

Answer (score 13):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) is for such issues, though you'll have to add more details than this.

However, Stack Exchange might not be the best place to find an answer in your case. It sounds like you need someone in front of the machine to diagnose the exact fault.